# naming a list with variable contents

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you use the contents of a variable to create a new list?

EDIT: To clarify, I should have 3 new lists after this is run. I should have a list named dev, test and prod.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

group_list = ['dev', 'test', 'prod']

for group in group_list:
    # this is obviously going to create a new list called group
    # i want to create a list using the contents of the "group" variable 
    group = []
```

Comment: do you mean something like `new_list = [ group ]`? Or do you mean a list *called* `dev` (the first time round), or what?

Comment: The fact that our three different answers answer three different questions suggests that your question isn't clear enough.  Could you provide some sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways of doing this, but the easiest is to use a dictionary instead.

```
group_dict = {group: [] for group in group_list}
```

This will leave you with a dictionary

```
{
   'dev': [],
   'test': [],
   'prod': []
}
```

which gives you access to all the handy pythonic tools when dealing with it. (Iteration, etc.)

Comment: Just use a dict. Don't try to create dynamic names in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** recommended and no matter what you are trying to do there **probably is** a better way, but this is *how strings can be converted to variable names*:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

group_list = ['dev', 'test', 'prod']

for group in group_list:
    globals()[group] = []

print(dev)  # -> []
     # ^ 'dev' is now a variable name!
```

---

The "magic" here happens because of `globals()` which is a `dictionary` where Python stores all the defined variables. Just like any other `dictionary` you can reach it and modify it. But don't.

Answer (score -1):

```
for g in group:
    exec(g + ' = []')
```

That would create lists named by the values in group. Be very cautious using 'exec`. Make sure it is YOUR code in the exec.

Comment: This answer gives you exactly the three lists as you mentioned in your clarification edit.